# Delete Subdirectories in a folder but keep individual files

Tags: batch

I am trying to make my own Batch file to delete the sub directories of a folder but keep files and the top level. I know I can just do `RMDIR <folderName> /S /Q` but I don't really want to do that for each folder if I can avoid it.

Is there a simple way of removing all folders in a directory but keeping the top level files?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to do this is:

```
FORFILES /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo rmdir @file /s /q"
```

if the output looks correct, remove the word echo. The command becomes:

```
FORFILES /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir @file /s /q"
```

Do note, the second command is irreversible. If it was in the wrong place, you lose data. So double, tripple check the first command before proceeding with the second. Make backups in case in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
for /d %i in (*)do rmdir /q /s .\"%~i"\.
```

---

Avoid using `forfiles` with `cmd /c`, follow **[ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)** advice, use `for /D` loop instead:

- ***```bat
  For /D Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders.
  ```***

---

- ***```bat
  Bugs

      Recent versions of FORFILES contain a bug, in processing command line arguments:
      running a /c command that contains an argument such as FORFILES /C "PING -a" will fail.
      The expected convention is that argv[0] will contain the program name, but FORFILES
      instead passes the first argument as argv[0]. Old versions e.g. FORFILES version 1.46
      (24th March 2006) do not suffer from this bug.
      
      One workaround for this is to include the program name as the first argument,
      this will be passed along by FORFILES and the CreateProcess call will then work
      as expected:
      FORFILES /c "Ping Ping -a".
      
      Alternatively pass the command to CMD /C, which will then process all the arguments
      correctly. If you want to use an internal commmand, or if you want to use redirection,
      pipe, command concatenation, etc, then you must use CMD /C.
      FORFILES /c "CMD /C Ping -a"
      
      There are some disadvantages to using CMD.exe with FORFILES, a new process will be
      created and destroyed for every file that FORFILES processes, so if you loop through
      1000 files, then 1000 copies of CMD.exe will be opened and closed, this will affect
      performance. Also any variable created with SET will be lost as soon as FORFILES moves
      on to the next file.
      

      In most cases using a simple FOR command along with Parameter extensions will provide
      a better/less buggy solution.
  ```***

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

[√] **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

[√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

[√] **[RD | RMDir /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**